# Ansible. How can I add new line after some regexp?

Tags: ansible

I need to add  lines in my default nginx config for load balancing. I have three servers in AWS and I want to make this config:

```
http {
    upstream myapp1 {
        #sting "server dns_server1_name.com;" there.
        #string "server dns_server2_name.com;" there.
        #string "server dns_server3_name.com;" there.
        ....
        ....
        #sting  "server dns_serverN_name.com;" there.
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        }
    }
```

I know I should use {{ ec2_public_dns_name }}, but how can I insert lines in default config? I want to dynamic add lines to file then I start playbook.

Comment: With Ansible you do not add lines incrementally, because this is not idempotent. You define which lines should be in the file and Ansible takes care that all lines are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vladimir-fomin, I am strongly discouraging you from using `lineinfile` module: it is very fragile.

It would be better to use `template`, utilizing a `{% for ... %}` loop.

Not a rocket science, configuration is put on your target host, and not worry about:

1. Idempotency (tm)
2. Changes in shipped defaults, they usually already allow inclusion of app specific configs, OR require very minimalistic downstream patch which which can be automated.
3. Losing control/stability of the content you're putting

I am usually putting template files in identical relative path under role's `templates` folder, here, e.g. under your role's templates folder, put the template under: `etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf.j2`

In it put your config, like:

```
    upstream {{app.name}} {
{% for alias in app.aliases %}
        #server {{alias}}.{{app.domain}}; there.

{% endfor %}
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://{{app.name}};
        }
    }
```

As you guessed you will have variable `app` with the corresponding details inside.

This would behave exactly as it looks like.
you could render this template like so:

```
- name: put nginx app config
  template:
    src:  '{{tpl}}.j2'
    dest: '/{{tpl}}'
    ...
  with_items:
  - 'etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: tpl
```

This code would be easier to maintain, IMHO, and require less attention.
And you always know that your file will look exactly as template states.

Note, the main nginx config file would need to be configured properly to include all .conf files under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` and you would need to make sure you include the correct level of config.

But I hope you're getting the idea.

:)

The above code would work, if you had variable:

```
app:
  name: myapp1
  domain: mydomain.com
  aliases:
  - name1
  - name22
  - name3
```

Also, this approach allows you to scale easily. To support multiple apps, you

Step 1: extend your variables:

```
apps:
  - name: myapp1
    domain: mydomain1.com
    aliases:
    - name1
    - name22
    - name3
  - name: myapp2
    domain: mydomain2.com
    aliases:
    - lalala
    - uquququ
    - lslsls
```

Step 2: update your task

```
- name: 'put nginx config of {{app.name}}'
  template:
    src:  '{{tpl}}.j2'
    dest: '/{{tpl|dirname}}/{{app.name}}.conf'
    ...
  with_items:
  - 'etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: tpl
```

Step 3: extract it as tasklist named myapps.yml

Step 4: execute that tasklist in a loop over apps variable:

```
- include: myapps.yml
  with_items: '{{apps}}'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: app
```

This means - you have a template that does not have to change for more apps.
you can make it more complex - to check for specific additional keys in `app` and add corresponding lines/pieces into config, If you need to.
And it would apply to ALL your apps.
So you can have different fields defined for different apps in `apps`, and it would be robust enough to use only what it has.

Isn't Ansible cool ?
:)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (not tested):

```
- lineinfile:
    line: 'server {{ ec2_public_dns_name }};'
    insertafter: 'upstream myapp1'
```

Comment: I have something like this:
`http {   
    upstream myapp1 {  
       server dns_server100_name.com  
    }`